# iFrame no meu site em wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

instalei o plugin `https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/` no meu site, e segui todas as orientações.

Na página que queria colocar o iFrame, inseri o código, só que não esta carregando a página que é necessário.

Alguém passou por isso, ou pode me ajudar?

Grato desde já!

Site que esta em branco: [site](http://ipecon.com.br/web/pre-escricao/)

Página que deve aparecer: [Formulario](http://ipecon.com.br/web/portal/formInscricao.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua página tem isso:

```
<div class="fusion-youtube-flash-fix">&shy;<style type="text/css"> iframe { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; } </style></div>
```

Remova essa tag `<style>` e seu conteúdo e deve resolver

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme, encontrei o código nesse caminho 'wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/class-avada-init.php', realizei a exclusão do código e tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @RegisAndrade se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema por favor marque-a como correta, se não entende como site funciona faça o [**tour**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)